# In Objective-c, safe and good way to compare 2 BOOL values?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, boolean, compare

I want to compare 2 BOOL values in objective-c.

I found out that (3)-(6) of the following code works.
(1)-(2) doesn't work because BOOL is just `signed char`.

(3) works and is very readable but I think `bool` isn't objective-c.
Using `bool` in objective-c code is good?

Which is the safe and good way to compare 2 BOOL values in objective-c?
Are there other better ways to compare?

```
BOOL b = YES;
BOOL c = 2;

NSLog(@"(1) %d", b == c); // not work
NSLog(@"(2) %d", (BOOL)b == (BOOL)c); // not work
NSLog(@"(3) %d", (bool)b == (bool)c);
NSLog(@"(4) %d", !b == !c);
NSLog(@"(5) %d", !!b == !!c);
NSLog(@"(6) %d", (b != 0) == (c != 0));
```

results:

```
(1) 0
(2) 0
(3) 1
(4) 1
(5) 1
(6) 1
```

Comment: `2` is not a valid `BOOL` value; only `YES` and `NO` are.  What you are doing is invalid.

Comment: The 4th method looks good to me. It is short, and it safely convert value to either 0 or 1.

Comment: @trojanfoe: The thing is, Obj-C will happily accept assignment of number to BOOL, and you can even do bitwise operation with it.

Comment: I'm agree with trojanfoe, and also I think XCode should generate warning in case of such assignments. Wrong BOOL assignments is a source of terrible bugs.

Comment: For XCode this is really difficult to find, because internally you are assigning integers even for YES and NO.

Comment: @trojanfoe From the compiler/language point of view `2` is a perfectly valid value for a `BOOL`.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Of course, however asking a question about safe usage of `BOOL` and then assigning `2`, isn't valid.

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks. I added a comment in Omar's answer. I explained the reason that assigning 2 to BOOL variable can happen.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134352/in-objective-c-safe-and-good-way-to-compare-2-bool-values/11134435#comment14594266_11134435

Comment: Assigning it to 2 is valid, however comparing the actual values of the BOOLs is not. Instead when you put the BOOLs into another boolean expression, then Objective-c will handle all values greater than 0 as true.

Comment: @jake_hetfield Assigning 2 is no problem. But assigning 256 is dangerous.
`BOOL b = 256; NSLog(@"b is %d", b);` results `b is 0`.
So, `if (b)` evaluated as false. But `if (256)` evaluated as true.

Comment: I agree, I wouldn't recommend assign a BOOL to anything else than true or false =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's perfectly valid to use `bool` in Objective-C as it's part of the C99 standard (§7.16). In my opinion it's also the best way to handle safe comparisons of boolean types.

The only reason not to use `bool` everywhere is that `BOOL` is omnipresent in Objective-C and the frameworks.

Comment: I use `bool` everywhere except where the Cocoa API calls for `BOOL`.  A safe conversion from one to the other would be (foo is bool and bar is BOOL):  `foo = bar ? true : false;` or `bar = foo ? YES : NO;`

Comment: thanks. i thought bool was c++. @JeremyP, why `foo = bar;` `bar = foo;` are not safe?

Comment: Assigning `true` or `false` to a `BOOL` is both valid and safe. The standard says they expand to the integer constants `0` or `1` (also in §7.16).

Comment: @js_ It always works.  Direct assignment should be safe too with modern non buggy compilers.

Comment: @JeremyP so why do you do `foo = bar ? true : false;` or `bar = foo ? YES : NO;`? XCode's compiler is buggy?

Answer (score 11):

Comparing two boolean values should be handled with an XOR operation.

Trying to compare the two booleans directly is a misuse of the fundamentals of Boolean Algebra:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(logic)

When you are doing

```
BOOL a = (b == c);
```

then this value may return false even if both b and c are true. However the expression b && c will always return YES if both b and c are true, i.e. greater than 0, and NO otherwise.

Instead this is what you are actually trying to do:

```
BOOL xor = b && !c || !b && c;
BOOL equal = !xor;
```

equivalent with

```
BOOL equal = !(b && !c || !b && c);
```

or

```
BOOL equal = (b && c) || (!b && !c)
```

If you have to spend time making sure that your BOOL values are normalized (i.e. set to either 1 or 0) then your doing something wrong.

Comment: thanks jake! i think you and @Sulthan are right. it's beautiful but it's longer and less readable/writable to me than !! or (bool). why c doesn't have logical xor operator?

Comment: readability can be improved from the variable names. If you for example wants to check if a person is either hungry but not tired or tired but not hungry, and you have two bools that are named the same, then the expression (hungry && !tired) || (!hungry && tired) makes more sense than the expression (hungry != tired). (How can hungry be equal to tired, and what would that mean?)

Comment: The 4th expression in the OP's question actually solves the problem fast and clean. It will just normalize the number to 0 or 1, then `==` will behave like XNOR (NOT XOR). Other expressions (3 and 5, 6) are also correct.

Comment: Programatically it is safe, and may be considered "clean" by some, but I stand with the opinion that a boolean expression should be a stand-alone expression that broken down to the use of && only and has the return value true or false. To compare two Boolean expressions with each other, normalized or not, is not regular boolean algebra. 
YES: if(true) if(false) if(bool1&&bool2) if(bool1 && !bool2 || int1==int2) if(int1==int2) and so on.
NO: if(bool1==bool2) if(bool1==true) if(!bool1==bool2) and so on.
They are all programatically correct, but the latter are not good looking to me.

Answer (score 4):

apart from the other answers, I would like to note that comparing bools for equality is **not** a very common operation. `BOOL` is not a type, it's just a macro which hides the fact that booleans are only integers. For every boolean operation, you should rather use programming structures and operators that can handle integers as booleans correctly:

e.g: 
`if (condition1 == NO) {}` should be `if (!condition1) {}`

`if (condition1 == condition2) {}`
 can be
`if ((condition1 && condition2) || (!condition1 && !condition2)) {}`
or better
`BOOL newCondition = (condition1 && condition2) || (!condition1 && !condition2);
if (newCondition) {}`

The shortest way to write a condition doesn't have to be the best way.

Comment: I don't think comparing boolean values is seldom. One common case is a setter for a BOOL property with a shortcut early return: - (void)setAnimate:(BOOL)animate { if (_animate == animate) return; // else do whatever it takes to set up or tear down animation }

Comment: Also, for the sake of correctness: `BOOL` is not a macro but a typedef.

Comment: Thanks for `typedef` note. The _old value check_ is something really special. Usually, you don't care about the property type at all and you don't even need to know it's a BOOL.

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131879/shorthand-for-all-bools-yes-or-all-bools-no

Answer (score 1):

Convert your number to a valid `BOOL`, by answering what do you mean by "2"

in your context, is 2 = YES

```
Int number = 2;
BOOL c = (number == 2); //2 is YES
```

is > 0 = YES

```
Int number = 2;
BOOL c = (number > 0); //2 is YES
```

It depends manly on what is TRUE and what is False in your application

Comment: Thanks. I always try to convert to valid BOOL when assigning after I learned that multiples of 256 are implicitly converted to 0(NO).
But it is possible that a method which other person made returns BOOL value other than 0/1.
And I don't convert returned BOOL value to valid BOOL like `b = !![obj methodWhchReturnsBOOL];`
So, `c = 2` can happen.

Comment: This kind of conversion is not necessary if you are using BOOLs correctly. If you need to think about that, then you are doing something fundamentally wrong. The expression (B && C) will return YES even if c is 2 and b is 1. It is possible to base all your code on these type of expressions, and that is the correct way in boolean algebra. (that is why it is called BOOL/bool/Boolean) See my answer for references.

Answer (score 1):

From `objc.h`:

```
typedef signed char     BOOL; 
....

#define YES             (BOOL)1
#define NO              (BOOL)0
```

Apparently, BOOL is `signed char`, so it is true that you can assign number to variable of `BOOL` type, which will mess up the comparison (since the comparison is integer comparison).

I think your (4) method using negation to convert arbitrary integral value to 0 or 1 is a good short way to safely compare the logical value of 2 BOOL.

Answer (score -1):

If you assign the integer 2 to a variable of type BOOL, your code is broken. Whatever you get after that, it's what you deserve.

Therefore, the only sensible way to compare two BOOLs a and b is

```
if (a == b) ...
if (a != b) ...
```

Comment: I would say, the only sensible way would be `if(a && b)` and `if (!a && b)`, as this operators will in dead be real boolean operations, while `==` and `!=` are numeric operators.