# Comparing two BOOL values

Tags: objective-c, ios, comparison, boolean

In my instance method, would like to compare a BOOL parameter with the content of a static variable, for instance:

```
- (NSArray*)myMethod:(NSString*)someString actualValuesOnly:(BOOL)actualValuesOnly {
static NSString *prevSsomeString;
static BOOL prevActualValuesOnly;
static NSArray *prevResults

if ([someString isEqualToString:prevSomeString] && 
              ([actualValuesOnly isEqual: prevActualValuesOnly]) 
               // HOW TO COMPARE THESE TWO BOOLEANS CORRECTLY?? 
    { return prevResults; }// parameters have not changed, return previous results 
else { } // do calculations and store parameters and results for future comparisons)
```

What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `BOOL` is a primitive (or scalar) type, and not a class, you can compare it directly with `==`

```
if ([someString isEqualToString:prevSomeString] && actualValuesOnly == prevActualValuesOnly)
```

Comment: Hi Matthias, thanks for your answer. I thought `BOOL`s are stored as `NSNumber` objects. Wouldn't `==` just compare their pointers and not their actual values?

Comment: BOOL is a primitive type like for example int or float. Compare it directly.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html

Answer (score 3):

Boolean variable is compare with == sign instead of isEqual

```
if(Bool1 == Bool2){

    // do something here}
```

Answer (score 1):

Boolean is compare with == sign instead of isequal:

Answer (score 1):

The solutions mentioned here are not the safest way to compare 2 BOOL values, because a BOOL is really just an integer, so they can contain more than just YES/NO values. The best way is to XOR them together, like detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11135879/1026573

Answer (score 0):

As Matthias Bauch suggests,

Simply do the comparison using **==** operator i.e

```
if (BOOL1 == BOOL2)   
{   
    //enter code here
}
```