# Obj-C: Is it really safe to compare BOOL variables?

Tags: objective-c

I used to think that in 64-bit Obj-C runtime BOOL is actually _Bool and it's a real type so it's safe to write like this:

```
BOOL a = YES; 
BOOL b = NO;
if (a != b) {...}
```

It's been working seemingly fine but today I found a problem when I use bit field structs like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    BOOL flag1 : 1;
} FlagsType;

FlagsType f;
f.flag1 = YES;

BOOL b = YES;

if (f.flag1 != b)
{
    // DOES GET HERE!!!
}
```

It seems that BOOL returned from the bit field is equal to -1 while the regular BOOL is 1, and they are not equal!!!

Note that I am aware of the situation when an arbitrary integer number is cast to BOOL and therefore becomes a "strange" BOOL which is not safe to compare.

However in this situation, both flag1 field and b were declared as BOOL and never cast. What is the problem? Is this a compiler bug?

The bigger question is if it's really safe to compare BOOLs at all or should I write a XORing helper function? (It would be such a chore, because boolean comparisons are so ubiquitous...)

Comment: The bit field type should be `int` or `unsigned int`, not `BOOL`.

Comment: BTW - you're not really comparing two `BOOL` values in your second example. You are comparing a `BOOL` and a "not really a `BOOL`".

Comment: "The bit field type should be int or unsigned int, not BOOL" who said that? And why is it -1?

Comment: Just about every Google search result for "C bit fields".

Comment: I think I get your point. If bit fields are returned as integers and BOOL is defined as signed char than it can be only -1 (YES) and 0 (NO). Thanks!

Comment: Then the answer to the bigger question: is it safe to compare BOOLs is yes? (except bit fields and integers cast to BOOLs)

Comment: You should see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134352/in-objective-c-safe-and-good-way-to-compare-2-bool-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not repeat that using a C boolean type solves the problems one can have with `BOOL`. That's true – in particular here, as you can read below –, but most of the problems resulted from a wrong storage into a boolean (C) object. But in this case `_Bool` or `unsigned` (`int`) seem to be the only possible solution. (Except of solutions with extra code.) There is a reason for it:

I cannot find a precise documentation of the new behavior of `BOOL` in Objective-C, but the behavior you found is something between bad and buggy. I expected the latest behavior to be analogous to `_Bool`. That's not true in your case. (Thanks for finding that out!) Maybe this is for backwards compatibility. To tell the full story:

In C an object of the type `int` is `signed int`. (This is a difference to `char`. For this type the signedess is implementation defined.)

> — int, signed, or signed int

ISO/IEC 9899:TC3, 6.7.2-2

> Each of the comma-separated sets designates the same type, […]

ISO/IEC 9899:TC3, 6.7.2-5

But there is a weird exception for historical reasons:

If the `int` object is a bit-field, it is implementation defined, whether it is a `signed int` or an `unsigned int`. (Likely this is because some CPUs in the past could not automatically expand the sign of a partial byte integer. So having an unsigned integer is easier, because nulling the top bits is enough.)

On clang the default is `signed int`. So according to full-width integers `int` always denotes a *signed* integer, even it has only one bit. An `int member : 1` can only store `0` and `-1`! (Therefore it is no solution to use `int` instead.)

> Each of the comma-separated sets designates the same type, except that for bit-fields, it is implementation-defined whether the specifier int designates the same type as signed int or the same type as unsigned int.

ISO/IEC 9899:TC3, 6.7.2-5

The C standard says that a boolean bit-field is an integer type and therefore takes part on the weird integer signedness rule for bit-fields:

> A bit-field is interpreted as a signed or unsigned integer type consisting of the specified number of bits.

ISO/IEC 9899:TC3, 6.7.2.1-9

This is the behavior you found. Because this is meaningless for 1 bit booleans types, the C standard explicitly denotes that storing a 1 into a boolean bit-field has to compare equal to 1 in every case:

> If the value 0 or 1 is stored into a nonzero-width bit-field of type _Bool, the value of the bit-field shall compare equal to the value stored.

ISO/IEC 9899:TC3, 6.7.2.1-9

This leads to the strange situation, that an implementation can implement booleans of width 1 as { 0, -1 }, but has to fulfill 1 == -1. Great.

So, the short story: `BOOL`  behaves like an integer bit-field (conforming to the standard), but does not take part on the extra requirement for `_Bool`s.

I think this is, because of legacy code. (One could expect -1 in the past.)