# iOS: Regular expression: match either quoted string or string without quotes

Tags: ios, regex, match, quotes, nsregularexpression

I need to match strings that either quoted from the both sides or strings that do not have leading and trailing quote at all.
I need to omit strings having single quote on the end - either leading or trailing quote.

Here are strings I have to **match**:

- "somecharsinside"
- somechars

I have **not to match**:

- "noquotefromtheright
- noquotefromtheleft"

I am trying something like this: `^\b.+|^\".^\"\b$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
^([^\"]*|\".*\")$
```

Either **any non-" chars** OR
**" + text + "**

Alternatively if you dont want to capture add `?:`

```
^(?:[^\"]*|\".*\")$
```

[regex101 Link](https://regex101.com/r/mN8cW4/1)

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for the answer!

Comment: For me I am trying to find all the quoted words in a string. For instance, `var str = "They said \"Its okay\", \"well\" didn't they?"`, should give these two quoted words/sentences. Can you help me ?

Comment: @nr5 you should ask a question for that. That question should include what the input is, what the output is supposed to be (and *why*) and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please see if you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57852915/find-quoted-words-in-a-string-with-regex

Answer (score 2):

This task can probably be done easier without regular expression:

```
if ([s hasPrefix:@"\""] == [s hasSuffix:@"\""]) {
    // String matches
}
```

Most likely it is safe to just use `==` here as per documentation both methods return YES on success, not an arbitrary non-zero value. But to be on safer side you could compare BOOLs as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11135879/137350)

Comment: I like that solution! :)